# Idea of multiple theme on a single channel in Sylius

Tags: symfony, themes, sylius

For my project I was in need of multiple theme designs for different devices, but in one channel now, can select just one theme.

For example, 
If I have channel "Japan" which sell in Japan, I want multiple themes for each devices : mobile, tablet and PC. So users will see the theme depend on their device.

I need some ideas about creating multiple theme/style for different devices with single channel.

So, Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Okay, so the service that is responsible for the current theme is the `sylius.context.theme` service. If you use Sylius full stack, then the `ChannelBasedThemeContext` will be used (see: https://github.com/Sylius/SyliusCoreBundle/blob/master/Theme/ChannelBasedThemeContext.php). As you can see in it’s source code, it simply finds a theme you have installed by theme `themeName` property on the current channel. Knowing this, we can implement our own by implementing `ThemeContextInterface`. Because in your case you probably want to fall back to the default behaviour when the theme `japan_mobile` does not exist, we are gonna decorate the `sylius.context.theme` service, instead of replacing it!

So let’s start by creating `Acme\AppBundle\Theme\DeviceBasedThemeContext`:

```
namespace Acme\AppBundle\Theme\DeviceBasedThemeContext;

use Sylius\Bundle\ThemeBundle\Context\ThemeContextInterface;
use Sylius\Bundle\ThemeBundle\Repository\ThemeRepositoryInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\ChannelContextInterface;
use Sylius\Component\Channel\Context\ChannelNotFoundException;
use Sylius\Component\Core\Model\ChannelInterface;

final class DeviceBasedThemeContext implements ThemeContextInterface
{
    /**
     * @var ThemeContextInterface
     */
    private $decoratedThemeContext;

    /**
     * @var ChannelContextInterface
     */
    private $channelContext;

    /**
     * @var ThemeRepositoryInterface
     */
    private $themeRepository;

    /**
     * @param ThemeContextInterface $decoratedThemeContext
     * @param ChannelContextInterface $channelContext
     * @param ThemeRepositoryInterface $themeRepository
     */
    public function __construct(
        ThemeContextInterface decoratedThemeContext,
        ChannelContextInterface $channelContext, 
        ThemeRepositoryInterface $themeRepository
    ) {
        $this->decoratedThemeContext = $decoratedThemeContext;
        $this->channelContext = $channelContext;
        $this->themeRepository = $themeRepository;
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getTheme()
    {
        try {
            /** @var ChannelInterface $channel */
            $channel = $this->channelContext->getChannel();

            $deviceThemeName = $channel->getThemeName().’_’.$this->getDeviceName();

            // try to find a device specific version of this theme, if so, it will use that one
            if ($theme = $this->themeRepository->findOneByName($deviceThemeName) {
                return $theme;
            }

            // fallback to use the default theme resolving logic
            return $this->decoratedThemeContext->getTheme();
        } catch (ChannelNotFoundException $exception) {
            return null;
        } catch (\Exception $exception) {
            return null;
        }
    }

    private function getDeviceName()
    {
        // here you should return the proper device name
        return ‘mobile’;
    }
}
```

Now that we have the theme context finished, we have to make the service container recognise it, we are doing that by decorating the existing `sylius.theme.context` service (a.k.a. the `ChannelBasedThemeContext`).

So in your `services.xml` add the following service:

```
<service id="acme.context.theme.device_based" class="Acme\AppBundle\Theme\DeviceBasedThemeContext"
         decorates=“sylius.theme.context”>
    <argument type=“service” id=“acme.context.theme.device_based.inner”/>
    <argument type=“service” id=“sylius.context.channel”/>
    <argument type=“service” id=“sylius.repository.theme”/>
</service>
```

And you are **done**! If you clear your caches it should now try to load `japan_mobile` first, if it does not exist it will simply load the `japan` theme (giving that the current channel has `japan` as its theme name).

I hope this is a clear enough instruction to help get you going, for injecting a service that can detect a proper device name is not so hard to do I guess, but if you can’t figure it out let me know and I will extend this by implementing that too.